# Motor Power for vertical lift in linear slide mechanism

Tags: motors, power, linear-motion, linear-motors

I want to pull up and down 10 kg metal cylinder at 7 inch vertically by using linear slide mechanism in 1 second. What should be the motor rpm, gear type, torque, watt etc? Otherwise how to calculate all those things? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you mix the metric with the standard?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat metric **is** standard. Much prefer using Watts to btu…

Comment: @SolarMike They tend to complain if I say English!  Something about a colonial war!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I referred to it a screw as an imperial screw once and they got super offended and said why wouldn't I just refer to it as an inch screw.

Answer (score 1):

Let's convert 7 inches to meters, 7x0.0254 = 0.1778m

You need a motor that can produce an average speed of 0.1778m/s so it must have an acceleration of 0.1778*2= 0.3556m/s^2

Now we can calculate the force your winch or motor needs. it must lift the 10kg against gravity and accelerate it

$$F = m \alpha+ mg= 10kg*0.3556m/s^2+10kg*9.8m/s^2 =10*10.155m/s^2$$

$$P_{average}=\frac{F*0.1778}{t}=101.5kgm/s= 9.81 * 101.5=995.715watts$$
I will detail the size of pulley later.

Comment: An improvement might be to convert kgm/s into something useable.

Comment: right, @Tiger Guy. i will.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer you should accept it, but there is also a benefit to waiting a couple of days (especially on this Stack), to see if there is a better one.